# Why $(t, \omega)\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is not measurable in following example?

Tags: probability, analysis, stochastic-processes

I want to find an example that r.v. $X_t:\Omega\to R$ is measurable but $(t, \omega)\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is not measurable.

If take a non-measurable set $B\subset [0,T]$, let $\Omega=\{-1, +1\}$. Then define
$$X_t=1_B(t) \mbox{ if } \omega=+1
$$
otherwise $X_t==1_{B^c}(t) \mbox{ if } \omega=-1$.

I can understand why $X_t$ is measurable because it is an indicator function. But why $(t, \omega)\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is not measurable?

Comment: Suppose $B$ is not measurable on the line (or on $[0, T]$) and set $X_t(\omega) = \mathbf{1}_B(t).$ Since this is a constant in $\omega,$ it is measurable (assuming constant functions are measurable on $\Omega$) but it is not measurable on $[0, T] \times \Omega$ for that would imply $X^{-1}(\{1\}) = B \times \Omega$ is measurable on $[0, T] \times \Omega$ and by projection, $B$ would be measurable on $[0, T].$

Comment: The source of confusion is probably that you think being an indicator function somehow implies the function is measurable: This is false, and you have an example, the indicator for some nonmeasurable set